# Creating and showing a Telerik RadNotification programmatically

Tags: c#, asp.net, notifications, telerik

I'm trying to have a RadNotification pop up in an event handler in my C# code. I tried something similar to this:

The markup,

```
<asp:button> ... OnClick="OnClick"</asp:button>
```

and the CodeBehind,

```
protected void OnClick(...) {
    new RadNotification().Show("Some text");
}
```

But that doesn't work. The Telerik documentation doesn't seem to have much info on creating these notifications in a CodeBehind.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This works for me...

**Markup**

```
<telerik:RadNotification ID="RadNotification1" runat="server" VisibleOnPageLoad="False" Width="300px" Height="100px" EnableRoundedCorners="true" EnableShadow="True" Title="My Notification" Position="Center" TitleIcon="none" />
<telerik:RadButton runat="server" ID="MyBtn" Text="Show Notification" OnClick="MyBtn_Click" />
```

**Code Behind**

```
protected void MyBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        RadNotification1.Show("Some text");
    }
```

Modify the RadNotification attributes as necessary.

Cheers

Answer (score 1):

When creating controls dynamically in ASP.NET WebForms, you must:

1. add them to the form (or a container in it), which you do not. It is also adviseable that you provide them with IDs
2. re-create them upon subsequent postbacks if they are going to be needed

This is not something specific to the Telerik controls, but it also applies to any control. Try adding a textbos with a preset text like this to see the problem.

Thus, Scotty's answer where the notification is simply declared in the markup is perhaps the most straightforward solution.

Comment: So you can't create a control in the codebehind without it being declared in the markup first?

Comment: You can, but you must add it to the Controls collection of the Page. Here is a basic article from MSDN on that: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kyt0fzt1(v=vs.100).aspx